# How do I properly use git workflow with rebase?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-workflow

I am using [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and am running into problems using the rebase feature of git. In short I need to reapply changes I already applied each time I rebase. I have recreated the problem using the steps below. Its a simplified version but the outcome was the same.

1. Developer A creates a git repo and adds a `contributors.txt` to `master`, commits and pushes. Now `master` has a `contributors.txt` file. The contents of the file is 

        `Developer A`
2. Developer A creates `branch-a` from `master`.
3. Developer B creates `branch-b` from `master`.
4. Developer A appends the contributors file in `branch-a` so it looks like.

        `Developer A
        Developer A2`
5. Developer B appends the contributors file in `branch-b` so it looks like

        `Developer A
        Developer B`
6. Developer A commits and pushes the changes to remote `branch-a`
7. Developer B commits and pushes the changes to remote `branch-b`.
8. Developer A merges `branch-a` with `master`.
9. Developer B checks out master and pulls so the local master gets updated with the changes applied by the merge mentioned in step 8 above.
10. Developer B checks out `branch-b` and does `git rebase master`
11. Developer B gets a merge conflict.
12. Developer B fixes the merge conflict so the file now looks like

         `Developer A
         Developer A2
         Developer B`
13. Developer B does `git add` to add the fixed conflict and runs `git rebase --continue`. All goes well.
14. Developer B pulls `branch-b` since now the local and remote `branch-b` has diverged they need to be merged. (Needs to set-upstream before pull)
15. Developer B resolves merge conflict, now the local `branch-b` has the changes from master and can be pushed to remote.
16. Developer B pushes `branch-b` to remote. using `git push origin branch-b`. All goes well.
17. Developer B creates a new file in `branch-b` and commits.
18. Developer B then does

    - `git checkout master`
    - `git pull` (master is up to date since it has not changed since last pull i.e. Step 9)
    - `git checkout branch-b`
    - `git rebase master`
19. When `git rebase master` is executed, git asks developer B to resolve the same conflicts all over again. Why does this happen? Shouldn't the already applied changes be known and not asked to be applied again?

I think I can use merge instead of rebase to overcome this problem. But it seems like I am using rebase incorrectly. Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After step 13, you should be able to do a `git push origin branch-b --force`.  This will push the rebased version to `branch-b` to your remote, and because it's been rebased on top of master, you should then be able to merge with master without any issue.

The issue with the previous method is that after rebasing on top of master, you're just adding the merge commit to origin/branch-b which hasn't been rebased on top of master so it's still diverged.  If you do a force push, then it just replaces the remote branch with your rebased branch.

Comment: I understand the solution. But am unclear on the issue. Isn't origin/branch-b rebased on top of master once I successfully complete step 13?

Comment: Your local branch-b has been rebased, but origin/branch-b has not because nothing was pushed after the rebase. That's why when you push there is still a merge conflict.

When you force push, it replaces the origin/branch-b with the rebased version.

Comment: Got it, thank you. It makes perfect sense now. Is there another workflow I should follow instead of this one? I guess if I want to use rebase this is the way to do it.